# using .loc to assign values from another dataframe by index returns : ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pandas-loc

df_state_group:

| Index | State | assigned_airport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Florida | NaN |
| 5 | Florida | NaN |
| 6 | Florida | NaN |
| 7 | Florida | NaN |

df1:

| Index | State | assigned_airport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Washington | NaN |
| 1 | New York | NaN |
| 2 | Illinois | NaN |
| 3 | Texas | NaN |
| 4 | Florida | NaN |
| 5 | Florida | NaN |
| 6 | Florida | NaN |
| 7 | Florida | NaN |
| 8 | Ohio | NaN |
| 9 | Colorado | NaN |
| 10 | Michigan | NaN |
| 11 | Indiana | NaN |

df_airports:

| Index | airports |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | d |
| 4 | e |
| 5 | f |

index_nearest_airport:

[3]

desired outcome:

df1:

| Index | State | assigned_airport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Washington | NaN |
| 1 | New York | NaN |
| 2 | Illinois | NaN |
| 3 | Texas | NaN |
| 4 | Florida | d |
| 5 | Florida | d |
| 6 | Florida | d |
| 7 | Florida | d |
| 8 | Ohio | NaN |
| 9 | Colorado | NaN |
| 10 | Michigan | NaN |
| 11 | Indiana | NaN |

df_state_group is a subset of df1 for the state of Florida

I have tried:

```
df1.loc[df_state_group.index, 'assigned_airport'] = df_airports.loc[index_nearest_airport,'airports'].values
```

but I keep on geting the error: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Comment: I think you forgot to add index_nearest_airport in your question

Comment: @Anurag Dabas It's right before the last df, with the value of [3]

Comment: Actually your values is having single element but where you are assigning will need 4 values. Hence length mismatch .

Comment: For Python 3.9 I can't comment. You are having single element in index_nearest_airport. But if there are more values I don't know the logic for assignment thing :/.

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
(df1.assign(assigned_airport= 
     pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df_airports.loc[index_nearest_airport,'airports'].values
     ,df_state_group.shape[0]), columns = ['assigned_airport'],index=df_state_group.Index)))
```

OR

```
(df1.loc[df_state_group.Index, 'assigned_airport'] = 
     np.repeat(df_airports.loc[index_nearest_airport,'airports'].values,
     df_state_group.shape[0]))
```

| Index | State | assigned_airport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Washington | NaN |
| 1 | New York | NaN |
| 2 | Illinois | NaN |
| 3 | Texas | NaN |
| 4 | Florida | d |
| 5 | Florida | d |
| 6 | Florida | d |
| 7 | Florida | d |
| 8 | Ohio | NaN |
| 9 | Colorado | NaN |
| 10 | Michigan | NaN |
| 11 | Indiana | NaN |

Comment: Thanks a lot that works perfectly, btw, does this has anything to do with python  3.9.6 update? since the previous code used to work fine until I have updated my python version, plus I noticed that it works if the array single value to be assigned is other than dtype = object